Java AWS SDK S3TransferManager throws exception: Failed to send the request. CRT error code: 1069
I have a simple S3TransferManager created using the following code:
StaticCredentialsProvider credsProvider = StaticCredentialsProvider.create(AwsBasicCredentials.create(amazonConfig.getAccessKeyId(), amazonConfig.getSecretKey()));
S3TransferManager xferMgr = S3TransferManager.builder()
  .s3ClientConfiguration(S3ClientConfiguration.builder()
    .credentialsProvider(credsProvider)
    .region(amazonConfig.getRegion())
    .build())
  .transferConfiguration(S3TransferManagerOverrideConfiguration.builder()
    .executor(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor())
    .build())
  .build();

The upload code is also simple:
final File docFile = new File("/path/to/file");
final PutObjectRequest putRequest = PutObjectRequest.builder()
  .bucket(amazonConfig.getBucket())
  .contentLength(docFile.length())
  .key(customKey)
  .contentMD5(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(MD5Checksum.createChecksum(docFile)))
  .build();
final CompletableFuture<CompletedFileUpload> cf = xferMgr.uploadFile(UploadFileRequest.builder()
  .putObjectRequest(putRequest)
  .source(docFile)
  .build()).completionFuture();

It seems that trying to upload to a bucket through the transfer manager fails with error:
software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException: Failed to send the request. CRT error code: 1069
I'm using sdk version 2.17.143 and specifically the -PREVIEW version for the s3-transfer-manager-2.17.143-PREVIEW.jar
Looking around I can't find what the error code means and it's not a bucket configuration issue as the same bucket was working in a previous version of the code.
